# Mysql Like bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
    $id='gsf';
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare('SELECT `title` FROM `post` WHERE (`content` LIKE `%?%`) and accepted=0 order by count desc Limit 0,5');
      $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($title);
      while($stmt->fetch();)
    {
      echo $title."<br>";         
      }
      $stmt->close();
      $mysqli->close();
```

This is a Php Snippet hen i execute it i get this error Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

what am i missing out??

Comment: `%?%` is the thing causing the problem

Comment: what should i use ?
should i test $id="%gsf";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare('SELECT `title` FROM `post` WHERE (`content` LIKE ?) and accepted=0 order by count desc Limit 0,5');

$stmt->bind_param('s',$id);

$id = '%gsf%'; //The **%** go here

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title);

while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
      echo $title."<br>";         
}

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is erronous, thus `$stmt` is not a prepared statement. Analyze the content of `$mysqli->errno` and `$mysqli->error` to find the problem in your SQL query.